Concat strings in a github context
How do you concatenate strings in a GitHub CI? I want to concatenate a variable coming from matrix. and with another part of the path. I've tried using join() it doesn't work.
name: ${{ join( [matrix.plugin.name, '/artifacts'], ',' ) }}

hashFiles(
I also don't see a concatenation operator anywhere.
I need to provide this to the hashfiles() I

One way to do that is with format, for example.
${{ format('{0}/artifacts', matrix.plugin.name) }}

Which can be provided to hashFiles like this
${{ hashFiles(format('{0}/artifacts', matrix.plugin.name)) }}

